# Cookie not created in AJAX request

Tags: php, plugin-development, ajax, cookies

I'm trying to set a cookie by php on a user interaction

```
function promo_signup () {
    $ip = get_client_ip();
    $entry = [
        'firstname' => $_POST['firstname'],
        'lastname' => $_POST['lastname'],
        'mail' => $_POST['mail'].'@student.unisg.ch',
        'state' => $_POST['state'],
        'time' => time(),
        'ip' => get_client_ip(),
    ];

    $mailing = get_post_meta( get_page_by_path('data')->ID, 'mailing', true );
    $mailing['promo']['clean'][$_POST['id']] = $entry;
    array_push($mailing['promo']['all'],$entry);
    update_post_meta( get_page_by_path('data')->ID, 'mailing', $mailing );

    setcookie('welcomeback',ucfirst($_POST['firstname']),strtotime('27 Feb 2017'),'/');
}
```

The the main purpose of the function works perfect and setcookie() returns true.

However, no cookie get's created when I reload the page

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['welcomeback'])) {
    echo "welcome back";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `COOKIEPATH` and `COOKIE_DOMAIN` constants.

`setcookie( 'welcomeback', ucfirst( $_POST['firstname'] ), strtotime( '27 Feb 2017' ), COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN );`